# Can't use google maps v1 on android 4.2.2

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm making an application using google maps api v1. The program runs fine in my 4.0.4 Android phone. But today after updating my phone to Android 4.2.2, my app no longer runs. It throws an IllegalStateException: Null Bitmap! at MapView.drawMap(). It seems like there's no loading_tile_android.png file. I'm really confused. Searching a lot but I find nothing that helps.

The logcat looks like this:

```
11-01 17:00:08.238: ERROR/MapView(8971): IllegalStateException on drawMap. Wiping cache.
11-01 17:00:08.238: ERROR/MapView(8971): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Null Bitmap! "loading_tile"; if seen during a test, this usually means that the image file needs to be added to the test.config file
11-01 17:00:08.238: ERROR/MapView(8971):     at com.google.common.graphics.android.AndroidImage.<init>(Unknown Source)
11-01 17:00:08.238: ERROR/MapView(8971):     at com.google.common.graphics.android.AndroidImageFactory.createImage(Unknown Source)
11-01 17:00:08.238: ERROR/MapView(8971):     at com.google.googlenav.map.MapTile.createTempImages(Unknown Source)
11-01 17:00:08.238: ERROR/MapView(8971):     at com.google.googlenav.map.MapTile.getTempImage(Unknown Source)
11-01 17:00:08.238: ERROR/MapView(8971):     at com.google.googlenav.map.MapTile.getImage(Unknown Source)
11-01 17:00:08.238: ERROR/MapView(8971):     at com.google.googlenav.map.Map.drawTile(Unknown Source)
11-01 17:00:08.238: ERROR/MapView(8971):     at com.google.googlenav.map.Map.drawMapBackground(Unknown Source)
11-01 17:00:08.238: ERROR/MapView(8971):     at com.google.googlenav.map.Map.drawMap(Unknown Source)
11-01 17:00:08.238: ERROR/MapView(8971):     at com.google.android.maps.MapView.drawMap(MapView.java:1048)
11-01 17:00:08.238: ERROR/MapView(8971):     at com.google.android.maps.MapView.onDraw(MapView.java:486)
11-01 17:00:08.238: ERROR/MapView(8971):     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6535)
```

Comment: Did your manufacturer update your phone? Or did you install some ROM mod?

Comment: @CommonsWare Thank you for answering! I use CM10.1 ROM. Is it the problem?

Comment: Quite possibly. Google Maps is a commercial component; ROM mod maintainers do not have the rights to distribute it or the SDK add-on AFAIK.